# Row update if row exists. Insert it if row doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server

I'm developing a SQL SERVER 2012 express and developer solution.

I will receive an xml in an stored procedure. In the stored procedure I will parse the xml and insert its data into a table.

My problem here is that in this xml could contain data that exists on the table, and I need to update the data on the table with the new one.

I don't want to check if each row in xml exists on the table.

I think I can use `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` but I'm not sure.

**How can I update or insert new data without checking it?**

This is the table where I want to insert (or update) the new data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CODES]
(
    [ID_CODE] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CODE_LEVEL] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [CODE] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [COMMISIONING_FLAG] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [IS_TRANSMITTED] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [TIMESPAN] [datetime] NULL,
    [USERNAME] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SOURCE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [REASON] [nvarchar](200) NULL
     CONSTRAINT [PK_CODES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [CODE_LEVEL] ASC,
        [CODE] ASC
    )
)
```

Comment: I suspect you want to use [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb510625.aspx), although this does not satisfy the criteria of "not checking it", but it does all run in a single statement. You can use `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` but more information would be required on your schema to say exactly how to use it. [This article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2013/02/01/a-creative-use-of-ignore-dup-key.aspx) is a pretty good place to start on `IGNORE_DUP_KEY`.

Comment: @GarethD I have added the table.

Comment: So after reading this [link](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2013/02/01/a-creative-use-of-ignore-dup-key.aspx [/link]
Everything is clear.you can decide what to do now ?

Comment: How would you identify an existing record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "IGNORE_DUP_KEY" parameter ,is ignore inserting new row, if he is already exists, but it is not dealing with update in case it exists.

the solution to your request is by MERGE or DML operation (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) .

BTW,
The parameter "IGNORE_DUP_KEY" is covering existsnce for the index key only (index column).